# Caching Pages via PHP

Tags: php, performance, caching, dynamic, server-side

I have a website with three pages x, y and z with a lot of content which is dynamically built in function of several database queries and many calculations. But, the content of pages x y and z is the same across different users. My question is, how do I cache this at best? What I've tried so far:

If a cache file does not exist, get the function `build_the_content()` which builds the HTML page content of the concerned page (as a returned concatenated HTML string), and write that string to the respective cache file using `file_put_contents()`. Then when the page is loaded, I do something like:

```
if ( file_exists( path_to_cache_file ) ) {

  readfile( path_to_cache_file ); 

} else {

  echo build_the_content();

}
```

I wonder if this is the best approach, or if there's better practice?

What's also important is how I wanna create the cache file(s): I have several admin pages programmed in the backend which are used to edit different sections of the pages x, y and z. When a client updates let's say a part of page x and y, I want to automatically update the cached files of page x and y. To be able to do this, I however need to update the affected page(s) in all locales, as `build_the_content()` uses [wordpress' native gettext localizations](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/). Can I somehow call a page in PHP on the server-side only for a specific locale to do so?

Comment: FWIW, caching is often best relegated to the webserver and/or CDN level. You don't need to make your code more complex with explicitly writing to files and such; you just need to set the right HTTP headers that tell client-facing HTTP endpoints that they can cache the content for a certain amount of time. If you use a CDN, that is *a lot* more efficient in every possible way, since PHP isn't even involved in serving the cached page then.

Comment: That's the thing, in theory I can cache 100% of the body without any time limit, it shall only change when part of its content is updated in the backend admin. That's why I was thinking that an approach using PHP caching triggered on admin edits is the best approach here. You don't agree on that for this use case?

Comment: It's a cost-benefit tradeoff. Is it *very* expensive to generate that page? Then you might want to cache that expensive data generation within PHP, so even if PHP gets invoked, it can do its job quickly. If this page *isn't* unusually expensive to generate though, then it shouldn't matter all that much whether PHP gets invoked or not. So for that case, HTTP caching is fine, and it can easily achieve 95%+ cache hits. The only other question then is about cache invalidation, and how quickly you require updates to propagate to visitors. HTTP caching is bad at immediate propagation.

Comment: Is this actually a WordPress site then? If so, maybe start looking into _transients_ first.

Comment: Thanks @deceze, yeah that's why I figured PHP may be the better way, but thanks for your infos mate, didn't know these things!

Comment: Also thx a lot to @CBroe, I didn't know about the Transients API, will try it out now and keep you posted about the result. The idea of using the database for caching gives me a weird feeling though, but I'll check it out. Cheers!

Comment: _“The idea of using the database for caching gives me a weird feeling though”_ - it shouldn’t necessarily. You are not trying to shave off fractions of milliseconds here of database vs. file system access, the core issue is that you have calculations that take a long time. So the major part here is to do that calculation only when necessary, which way exactly the result of that gets stored & accessed, is really secondary.

Comment: Alright. One last thing, the website has tons of images. Apart from resizing / scaling them appropriately, I wonder if it's actually possible to sort of cache them with transients too? Including just the markup with their urls as the src of the img tag will not bring any additional benefits I guess? I'll try it out anyway, but if you may have another ace up your sleeve for the (server-side) caching of imgs, if that's even possible..?

Comment: The images are all superposed above each other using ```position:absolute``` (they bleach above each other using ```opacity:0``` and ```opacity:1``` transitions), so I guess lazy loading is not an option here, except if I may change the slider to slide left and right out of the viewport using margins..?